# LESS css default values

Tags: css, less

I am trying to have a LESS mixin use a default value if a variable is not set but my code always uses the default value.  I am trying:

```
@color : red;

.mixin (@color : blue)
    {
    color: @color;
    }

.block {.mixin()}
```

and I am getting blue.  In this instance, I want it to be red.  Is there another way to do this?  Am I missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line you'll want to pass in the color you want, in this case for red, it's defined as `@color` globally:

`.block {.mixin(@color)}`

Without passing in a color, the parameter will be the default blue as defined in the `.mixin` definition.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, please accept it by checking the green checkmark next to the answer so this question will be closed.

Comment: The will generate `.block{ color: }` if `@color` hasn't been set. The OP wants it to generate `.block{ color: blue }`.

Comment: The solution I finally came up with was to set the value to red, and later import a LESS settings file with a optional value of blue. If the var is set in the settings file it will be blue, otherwise it will be red.  This make sense in the broader scope of things anyway.